# Regular expressions practice/learning resources

Tags: regex

Can any of you recommend an online series of regular expression problems, preferably with solutions?  Maybe some cs class problem set or something of that ilk?

Without using them frequently, I tend to forget everything but the very, very basics, so I'd like to be able to do some problems to really internalize the info.

Thanks!

Comment: People frequently post "questions" here asking others to write regular expressions for them. Practice solving those. See if you can get your answer accepted. As a bonus, it'll help boost your rep. ;-)

Comment: See, you could have gotten [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690986/regex-needed-to-match-number-to-2-decimal-places). Look for the ones that start with "Regex needed". That's the sign of a good question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use IRC, you can try the regex quiz in #regex on [Undernet](http://www.undernet.org/).

It has a bunch of problems and suggested reading for solving them.

Comment: haven't been on IRC since, like 2001, but i will check this out :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
http://www.regexbuddy.com/

And this:
http://regexlib.com/