# RegEx needed to match number to exactly two decimal places

Tags: regex

I need some regex that will match only numbers that are decimal to two places. For example:

- 123 = No match
- 12.123 = No match
- 12.34 = Match

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
^[0-9]*\.[0-9]{2}$ or ^[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]$
```

Answer (score 29):

```
var regexp = /^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$/;

//returns true
regexp.test('10.50')

//returns false
regexp.test('-120')

//returns true
regexp.test('120.35')

//returns true
regexp.test('120')
```

Comment: Did you read the question They don't want to match integer. And they want to match exactly 2 decimal.

Answer (score 11):

If you're looking for an entire line match I'd go with Paul's answer.

If you're looking to match a number within a line try: `\d+\.\d\d(?!\d)`

- `\d+`    One or more digits (same as `[0-9]`)
- `\.`    Matches to period character
- `\d\d`    Matches the two decimal places
- `(?!\d)` Is a negative lookahead that ensures the next character is not a digit.

Answer (score 5):

It depends a bit on what shouldn't match and what should and in what context

for example should the text you test against only hold the number? in that case you could do this:

```
/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}$/
```

but that will test the entire string and thus fail if the match should be done as part of a greater whole

if it needs to be inside a longer styring you could do

```
/[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}[^0-9]/
```

but that will fail if the string is is only the number (since it will require a none-digit to follow the number)

if you need to be able to cover both cases you could use the following:

```
/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}$|[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}[^0-9]/
```

Comment: Interesting approach.  I'm not sure it would happen a number at the end of a longer string.  I'd suggest your last line could be changed to `/[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}([^0-9]|$)/`

Answer (score 2):

You can also try Regular Expression

```
^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$

or
var regexp = /^\d+\.\d{0,2}$/;

// returns true
regexp.test('10.5')

or
[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}

or
^[0-9]\d{0,9}(\.\d{1,3})?%?$

or
^\d{1,3}(\.\d{0,2})?$
```