# How to make edittext entries to 2 digit floating numbers in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am a beginner in android.I have a edittext in my activity.I need to make the edittext entries to two digit floating numbers after user enter the data.For example if the user enters 100 then after completion it should display as 100.00, if user enters 450.468 it should display as 450.47 in the edittext.How to do this? Please help me.

Comment: What's the flow of the application you are creating? Is it just an edittext where the user enters a number and hits a submit button? In this case you can just use the Math.round function like this (double roundOff = (double) Math.round(a * 100) / 100;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ravi's answer along with TextChangeListener on edittext as

```
textMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    String FormattedText=form.format(UserEnteredValue);
    textView.setText(FormattedText);
}
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}});
```

Comment: what should be the type of UserEnteredValue.is it a string?

Comment: No its not string you have to type cast it to double, you can do something like                                                                                       String FormattedText=form.format(Double.parseDouble(UserEnteredValue));

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String seq=editTextt.getText();
double d=Double.parseDouble(seq);
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
editTextt.setText(""+formatter.format(d));
System.out.println(formatter.format(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code -

```
DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
String FormattedText=form.format(UserEnteredValue);
textView.setText(FormattedText);
```

hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I think in that case you have to use **InputFilter** looks into the below solution that will same as your problem.

[How to limit EditText length to 7 integers and 2 decimal places?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423483/how-to-limit-edittext-length-to-7-integers-and-2-decimal-places)

[Limit Decimal Places in Android EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357455/limit-decimal-places-in-android-edittext)

hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
textMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    String FormattedText=form.format(UserEnteredValue);
    textView.setText(FormattedText);
}
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}});
```

Comment: Could you also explain your answer? Answers are always stronger if they include some kind of explanation.