# Unresolved reference: DecimalDigitsInputFilter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-input-filter

I get this code when I call

```
EditText.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(InputFilter.LengthFilter(7),DecimalDigitsInputFilter(2))
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 class DecimalDigitsInputFilter( maxDecimalPlaces: Int) : InputFilter {
            private val pattern: Pattern = Pattern.compile(
                "[0-9]"  + "+((\\.[0-9]{0,"
                        + (maxDecimalPlaces - 1) + "})?)||(\\.)?"
            )
    
            override fun filter(
                p0: CharSequence?,p1: Int,p2: Int,p3: Spanned?,p4: Int,p5: Int
            ): CharSequence? {
                p3?.apply {
                    val matcher: Matcher = pattern.matcher(p3)
                    return if (!matcher.matches()) "" else null
                }
                return null
            }
        }
```

Implementation in activity

```
  etContactUsName.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(DecimalDigitsInputFilter(maxDigitsAfterDot))
```

Comment: Thanks. Did you convert code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423483/how-to-limit-edittext-length-to-7-integers-and-2-decimal-places)? For me optimizing imports and formatting code forever (5 mins) when I tried to convert.