# Extracting decimal number upto two precision using regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string, and I need to extract decimal number upto two precision using Regex function in Javascript.

or example, if I have string "RequestedAmount-12.20", I need to get the output as 12.20 and not 12.2. The regex I am using, gives me 12.2.

Here is the Regex I used.

```
str="RequestedAmout-12.20"
requestedamt = Number( str.replace( /[^0-9\.]+/g, "" ) );
```

I should get 12.20

Comment: The number `12.2` is exactly the same as the number `12.20`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4691032/3832970. Use `String#match()` to get the value.