# How to check and set if/else condition that a value is only has two decimal points?

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, integer, decimal

i'm writing a function and need to ensure that all of the inputs are correct before I do anything with them. one thing I need to do is check whether there are exactly 2 decimal points in a number. i can't figure out how to write this in an if/else condition.

for example:

```
2.22 = true
1.00 = true
10.32 = true
100.11 = true
12.1 = false
1.044 = false
```

I currently have the function checking that there is a decimal point, and that the value is a number like this:

```
 else if (data === "" || !data.includes('.') || isNaN(data) || !data=.split(".")[1].length > 3)) {...}
```

how would I go about doing this??

Comment: Use regex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690986/regex-needed-to-match-number-to-exactly-two-decimal-places

Comment: https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285

Comment: this doesn't work - it seems to make everything an error, regardless of whether it is the correct amount of decimal points

Comment: If you are declaring these as numbers then it's a meaningless check (`1.00 === 1`). If you are you passing them as strings then either use a regex or simply use [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to force the correct number of decimal places

Comment: i don't want to force the correct decimal place, I want to check whether the data being inputted has a certain number of decimal places. but I ended up getting regex to work, so all is well!

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this, use the JavaScript Split method. This method splits a string into an array based on the decimal point. Then you can check whether the second element (that is, the fractional part) of the split array has length 2.

```
function checkTwoDecimalPoints(data) {
    var dataString = data.toString();
    if (dataString === "" || !dataString.includes('.') || isNaN(data)) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var decimalPart = dataString.split(".")[1];
        if (decimalPart.length === 2) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```